# JRuby Rails tutorial ForbiddenAttributesError issue with strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Im doing the tutorial on rails website
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I have added def article_params but it makes no difference and i still get ForbiddenAttributesError when submitting the form.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

I can change params.require to be whatever i like and it makes no difference so im assuming it doesnt even get that far.

I am on latest jruby on windows 
jruby 1.7.13 (1.9.3p392) and rails 4.1.4

Im a complete newb with ruby and rails.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `params` directly. You have to use `article_params`.

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

Have a look at [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)